# How to solve a linear ridge regression.

Tags: linear-regression

The below is some part of this thesis.

https://kaiminghe.github.io/publications/pami12guidedfilter.pdf.

I could not understand how equation (4) is calculated.
I know that I need to do “partial differentiation $=0$” of (2).
I tried to get equation (4). But the result is not same.
Please let me know how the equation (4) is calculated from (2) and (3).

---

Now we define the guided filter. The key assumption of the guided filter is a local linear model between the guidance $I$ and the filtering output $q$. We assume that $q$ is a linear transform of $I$ in a window $\omega_k$ centered at the pixel $k$:

$$q_i=a_k I_i+b_k, \forall i \in \omega_k \tag1$$

where $a_k$, $b_k$ are some linear coefficients assumed to be
constant in $\omega_k$.

We seek a solution that minimizes the difference between $q$ and $p$ while maintaining the linear model. Specifically, we minimize the following cost function in the window $\omega_k$:

$$E\left(a_k, b_k\right)=\sum_{i \in \omega_k}\left(\left(a_k I_i+b_k-p_i\right)^2+\epsilon a_k^2\right) \tag2$$

Here, $\epsilon$ is a regularization parameter penalizing large $a_k$.

This equation is the linear ridge regression model and its solution is given by

$$b_k=\bar{p}_k-a_k \mu_k \tag3$$

$$a_k=\frac{\frac{1}{|\omega|} \sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i p_i-\mu_k \bar{p}_k}{\sigma_k^2+\epsilon} \tag4$$

Here, $\mu_k$ and $\sigma_k^2$ are the mean and variance of $I$ in $\omega_k,|\omega|$ is the number of pixels in $\omega_k$, and $\bar{p}_k=\frac{1}{|\omega|} \sum_{i \in \omega_k} p_i$ is the mean of $p$ in $\omega_k$.
We obtained the linear coefficients $\left(a_k, b_k\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by myself.
By partial differentiation of equation 2,

$\begin{aligned} & \sum_{i \in \omega_k}\left\{2 I_i\left(a_k I_i+b_k-p_i\right)+2 \varepsilon a_k\right\}=0 \\ & \sum_{i \in \omega_k}\left\{I_i\left(a_k I_i+b_k-p_i\right)+\varepsilon a_k\right\}=0 \\ & \sum_{i \in \omega_k}\left\{I_i\left(a_k I_i+b_k\right)+\varepsilon a_k\right\}=\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i p_i \\ & b_k=\bar{p}_k-a_k \mu_k \\ & \sum_{i \in \omega_k}\left\{I_i\left(a_k I_i+\bar{p}_k-a_k \mu_k\right)+\varepsilon a_k\right\}=\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i p_i \\ & \sum_{i \in \omega_k}\left\{I_i\left(a_k I_i-a_k \mu_k\right)+\varepsilon a_k\right\}=\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i p_i-\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i \bar{p}_k \\ & a_k \sum_{i \in \omega_k}\left\{I_i\left(I_i-\mu_k\right)+\varepsilon\right\}=\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i p_i-\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i \bar{p}_k \\ & a_k=\frac{\frac{1}{|\omega|}\left(\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i p_i-\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i \bar{p}_k\right)}{\frac{1}{|\omega|} \sum_{i \in \omega_k}\left\{I_i\left(I_i-\mu_k\right)+\varepsilon\right\}} \\ & a_k=\frac{\frac{1}{|\omega|}\left(\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i p_i-\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i \bar{p}_k\right)}{\frac{1}{|\omega|} \sum_{i \in \omega_k}\left\{I_i\left(I_i-\mu_k\right)+\varepsilon\right\}}=\frac{\frac{\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i p_i}{|\omega|}-\bar{p}_k \frac{\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i}{|\omega|}}{\frac{\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i^2}{|\omega|}-\mu_k \frac{\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i}{|\omega|}+\frac{\Sigma_{i \in \omega_k} \varepsilon}{|\omega|}} \\ & a_k=\frac{\frac{1}{|\omega|} \sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i p_i-\bar{p}_k \mu_k}{\frac{\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i^2}{|\omega|}-\mu_k^2+\varepsilon}=\frac{\frac{1}{|\omega|} \sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i p_i-\mu_k \bar{p}_k}{\sigma_k^2+\varepsilon} \\ & \sigma_k^2=\frac{\sum_{i \in \omega_k} I_i^2}{|\omega|}-\mu_k^2 \\ & \end{aligned}$

$\sigma_k^2=\ \frac{\sum_{i\in\omega_k}\left(I_i-\mu_k\right)^2}{\left|\omega\right|} \\
       = \frac{\sum_{i\in\omega_k}{(I_i^2-{2\mu}_kI_i+\mu_k^2)}}{\left|\omega\right|} \\
       = \frac{\sum_{i\in\omega_k}\ I_i^2}{\left|\omega\right|}\ -\frac{{2\mu}_k\sum_{i\in\omega_k}\ I_i}{\left|\omega\right|} + \frac{\sum_{i\in\omega_k}\mu_k^2}{\left|\omega\right|} \\
       = \frac{\sum_{i\in\omega_k}\ I_i^2}{\left|\omega\right|}\ -{2\mu}_k^2+ \mu_k^2 \\
       = \frac{\sum_{i\in\omega_k}\ I_i^2}{\left|\omega\right|}\ -\mu_k^2  \\
\sigma_k^2=\frac{\sum_{i\in\omega_k}{(I_i-\mu_k)}^2}{\left|\omega\right|}=\frac{\sum_{i\in\omega_k}\ I_i^2}{\left|\omega\right|}-\mu_k^2 \\$

It was proved.